# OpenCV detect corners of a pattern hidden in a image

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, image-processing

I have to create a mobile application able to detect hidden (standard) pattern in a image.

The purpose is to detect corners and get some information from image (like a link).

I'm focusing on iOS for the moment but I don't know how implement the pattern and recognize it with OpenCV

So the first question is: **how can I add hidden information in a image?**

I found [this library](https://github.com/isena/ISStego) that implement *steganography* to hide some information in a image. Is this the right way?

Next step is detect with the phone's camera the image and the its corners. My idea is to create a standard pattern (like points or lines) to add on a .png image and use template matching to detect, during capture, the area where the pattern is present. But reading online I have saw that this technique is not the best for this problem.

I have successfully implemented the HSV conversation for color-tracking following [this tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/) but I don't know how to proceed to the next step.

So, the second question is: **how can I recognize a standard pattern and detects corners in a frame captured with the camera?**

This is the code that I use to convert the sample buffet to UIImage:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    uint8_t *yBuffer = (uint8_t*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    size_t yPitch = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    uint8_t *cbCrBuffer = (uint8_t*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1);
    size_t cbCrPitch = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1);

    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    uint8_t *rgbBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(width * height * bytesPerPixel);

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        uint8_t *rgbBufferLine = &rgbBuffer[y * width * bytesPerPixel];
        uint8_t *yBufferLine = &yBuffer[y * yPitch];
        uint8_t *cbCrBufferLine = &cbCrBuffer[(y >> 1) * cbCrPitch];

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int16_t y = yBufferLine[x];
            int16_t cb = cbCrBufferLine[x & ~1] - 128;
            int16_t cr = cbCrBufferLine[x | 1] - 128;

            uint8_t *rgbOutput = &rgbBufferLine[x*bytesPerPixel];

            int16_t r = (int16_t)roundf( y + cr *  1.4 );
            int16_t g = (int16_t)roundf( y + cb * -0.343 + cr * -0.711 );
            int16_t b = (int16_t)roundf( y + cb *  1.765);

            rgbOutput[0] = 0xff;
            rgbOutput[1] = clamp(b);
            rgbOutput[2] = clamp(g);
            rgbOutput[3] = clamp(r);
        }
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbBuffer, width, height, 8, width * bytesPerPixel, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);
    free(rgbBuffer);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    return image;
}
```

And this is for HSV conversation:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
  fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
  @autoreleasepool {
    if (self.isProcessingFrame) {
        return;
    }
    self.isProcessingFrame = YES;

    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    cv::Mat matFrame = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];

    cv::cvtColor(matFrame, matFrame, CV_BGR2HSV);
    cv::inRange(matFrame, cv::Scalar(0, 100,100,0), cv::Scalar(10,255,255,0), matFrame);

    image = [self UIImageFromCVMat:matFrame];

    // Convert to base64
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

    self.isProcessingFrame = NO;
  }
}
```

I hope some help, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into this. https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html

Comment: Useful to detect corners, thanks. But is not enough for me because I have to check if inside the area is present a pattern to extract hidden information (like a link to a resource) to display a content (like a video) in overlay the area of interest...

Comment: I feel there are multiple issues with this question. Firstly, it's asking more than one question. The first question sounds too broad. A better question would be how to implement *X technique* for hiding information in your medium. The second question deals with detection, but that goes hand in hand with your secret embedding method, i.e., the reverse procedure. Also, asking if something is the right way to do steganography is too broad. You have to define your requirements and then choose an algorithm that satisfies them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The principal issue for is how to approach the the problem. I have propose some solutions but I don't know the what the best is...

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you want to hide information in an image and when you take a photo of that image with the camera of a phone, you want to be able to see if an image contains a secret in the designated area and if yes, to extract it. If that's it, you can't simply use pixel lsb substitution steganography, because when you take a photo of an image, the variable distance from the photo (size) and the lighting of the setting practically guarantee for pixels to have different values, thereby destroying the secret.

Comment: Yes, the problem is very complicated and I don’t know how approach the solution...